# Response Redirect on Postback

Tags: asp.net

My code looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(IsPostback)
   {
      if(/* User is not authenticated to perform any actions on this page */)
      {
        Response.Redirect(/* Error Page */);
      }
   }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /* do some stuff */
}
```

I would have guessed that if I submit the button to do a postback and I was not authenticated, then in the Page_Load the redirect would happen and would send back an HTTP 302. However, it appears that it runs the Response.Redirect line of code, keeps processing past it in Page_Load, and then even runs `btnSubmit_Click` afterwards. The response is not the error page.

I can put a `return` call after the Response.Redirect to prevent further processing in that function, but the `btnSubmit_Click` function will still get run.

Why would it work this way?

Comment: +1. That's very strange. On My PC, an exact version of your code, does not execute the `btnClick`; it redirects immediately.

Comment: Are you by chance catching some exceptions in Page_Load? Normally, `Response.Redirect` throws `ThreadAbortException` which prevents ASP runtime from further processing your request. However, if you swallow the exception, the processing continues. I put this in a comment not in an answer because of the question I ask at the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent more code from processing, use this:

```
Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

The second parameter will end further processing instead.

Comment: This seems to work, but now I am wondering if there is any case when Page_Load wouldn't get called on a postback and if it is safe to put all authentication code in the Page_Load instead of each individual handler?

Comment: `Page_Load` should always be called so that's safe. However, you may also consider looking at handling authentication checks in configuration (web.config).

Comment: +1. While this answer obviously works, I wonder why on my test I do NOT need to pass `true` on the second parameter and my click event handler still doesn't fire.

Comment: This still throws exception- "Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback."